# data-rel in .attr (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to add a data-rel to my javascript .attr Here is the original attr:

```
link.attr('href',obj.images.standard_resolution.url);
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
link.attr('href data-rel="lightframe"',obj.images.standard_resolution.url);
```

I also tried to making all the a links include it but with no luck:

```
$('a').attr('data-rel', 'lightframe');
```

Is this even possible? if so, what would be the correct syntax to use? I had a good read at http://api.jquery.com/attr/ but did not solve my issue?

EDIT: Markup here:

```
function ProcessData(response){
    if(response != null){
        var ul = $('<ul/>');
        ul.attr({'class': tag_name});

        $(response.data).each(function(index,obj){
            if(index == 20)
                return response.pagination.next_url;
            var link = $('<a/>'), image = $('<img/>'), li = $('<li/>');

            image.attr({'src': obj.images.standard_resolution.url,
                        'width':thumb_dimension,'height': thumb_dimension});

            link.attr({'href' : obj.images.standard_resolution.url,'data-rel' : 'lightcase'});  
            image.appendTo(link);
            link.appendTo(li);


            if(include_username){
                $('<div class="username">'+obj.from.username+'</div>').appendTo(li);
            }
            if(include_caption){
                $('<div class="caption">'+obj.caption.text+'</div>').appendTo(li);
            }
            // Append the image (and text) to the list
            ul.append(li);
        });
        // Append the list to the given div
        $(div_to_add_pics).append(ul);
        // make url correlate to the next set of data
        url = response.pagination.next_url;

    }
};
```

Comment: @TusharGupta Is this enough? or should I include the full `function`

Comment: how come you're using the correct syntax in the image attr...

Comment: img attr pulls the source of img, link attr pulls link. Having zero luck, no matter what I try.

Comment: possible whatever library you are using only binds its events at the page load, so by time you add the `rel` attributes it has already ran so it is too late.

Comment: @Chad this makes sense. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Completely depends on whatever library you are using, and how it works. Likely the best people to ask are the devs (forum, irc, github issue, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var link = $('<a/>')
link.attr({
    'href': obj.images.standard_resolution.url,
    'data-rel' : 'lightframe'
});
```

or

```
link.attr('data-rel', 'lightframe');
```

Comment: I have added the full function, maybe this can help? you a bit more? I have been stuck for hours.